# Get HTML in JSON to render as HTML in React Component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Trying to figure out how can i get the link to actually render as a link.  Right now after i read this line of text from my Json file, react renders the hyperlink as literal text, it doesn't render it as a link.

**someData.json**

```
[{
    "about":   "John has a blog you can read <a href=\"http://www.john.com/blog/\" target=\"_blank\">here</a>."
}]
```

**someComponent.js**

```
const Person = Component({
    store: Store('/companies'),
    render(){
        var company = this.store.value()[this.props.companyId];

        return (
            <div id='ft-interviewee className="all-100"'>
                <p className="section-heading bold padding-top-20 font-22">Person</p>
                <div className="column-group horizontal-gutters">
                    <div className="all-10">
                        <div>{company.people.person.about}</div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't put an anchor tag inside of the `img` tag's `src` attribute...

Comment: crap bad post, hold on

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html)

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: company.people.person.about } }></div>
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/gc4q0ox1/)

Answer (score 0):

Another option and I think cheap to use is NPM React Plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser

I have used this and feeling good.

Comment: Using an extra package instead of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` looks like overkill.

Comment: even I was not aware at that. Its 2 year old comment

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to just get a ref on the container which will contain the HTML and then just set its innerHTML to the HTML-string which should be rendered.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).