# How do I display JSON data with HTML tags applied, in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I have JSON data with bunch of html tags attached in between. I've fetched & displayed the data as below.

```
componentDidMount() {
        this._callCake();
    }

_renderEachCake = () => {
    return (
        <EachCake 
        image={this.state.cake_object.image}
        body={this.state.cake_object.body}
        />
    );
  };

_callCake = () => {
        return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cake/1`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({cake_object : data})
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Row className="justify-content-center">
                    <Col><CakeHeader /></Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className="justify-content-center">
                    <Col>this._renderEachCake()</Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}
```

However when I see the data on the screen, I see all the "raw" data with html tags attached, not applied. Like below:

```
<p>&nbsp;<span style="font-size: 1rem;">This is how</span>all the text<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"> look like</span>
```

I cannot use `replace()`, because I need the tags applied to the text. 
Any recommendations? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get HTML in JSON to render as HTML in React Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797056/get-html-in-json-to-render-as-html-in-react-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing HTML inside react component you should use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` like this :

```
  <div
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data.content }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use React's [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://linguinecode.com/post/complete-guide-react-dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to set the HTML content, instead of text content, of an element

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: data.path.to.element } }></div>
```